# Make SpatRaster from sf point object

Tags: r, geospatial

I'm working through old code to convert things from `stars` and `raster` to `terra`. How can I make a `SpatRaster` from a `sf` point object that has equally spaced coordinates? I can do it by taking the `sf` object and making is a `data.frame` before using `rast`. Is this the best way to go from `foo_sf` to `foo_rast`?

```
library(sf)
library(terra)
tmp <- expand.grid(x=1:10,y=1:10)
tmp$z <- runif(100)

foo_sf <- st_as_sf(tmp,coords=c("x","y"))
# convert to a df and then to SpatRaster?
foo_df <- data.frame(st_coordinates(foo_sf),z=foo_sf$z)
foo_rast <- rast(foo_df)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rast(foo_df, type="xyz")`. Here showing that with `tmp` which has the same structure

```
library(terra)
tmp <- expand.grid(x=1:10,y=1:10)
tmp$z <- 1:100

foo_rast <- rast(tmp, type="xyz")
```

Comment: Thanks. My goal is to go from sf point to SpatRaster (foo_sf to foo_rast in the example) in a single step if possible as I'll be working with interpolated surfaces that are output from gstat as sf.

Comment: Then you can avoid all of this if you use `terra::interpolate`

Comment: I'm working up the courage to convert a large workflow to all be in terra. So I guess it's time to take the plunge. And thanks for all the materials you have to make that transition!

Answer (score 0):

That's one option. The second one is to convert `tmp_sf` to `terra::vect()` object, rasterize it and assign values:

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.11.1, GDAL 3.6.2, PROJ 9.1.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
library(terra)
#> terra 1.7.71
tmp <- expand.grid(x=1:10,y=1:10)
tmp$z <- runif(100)

foo_sf <- st_as_sf(tmp,coords=c("x","y"))

r <- foo_sf |>
  terra::vect() |>
  terra::rast()

terra::values(r) <- foo_sf$z
terra::plot(r)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-03-27 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Please note, there is `terra::rasterize()` function which allows you to rasterize spatial geometries to raster, but that's more for non equally spaced geometries :).

Comment: This works for a 10x10 raster, as in the example, but not for other dimensions.